# PHP regex: make links NOT clickable in menu. remove link but keep anchor

Tags: php, regex, replace, hyperlink, anchor

I have replacement which I want improve for removing links from menu.

```
   $n=extract(
  preg_replace(
     array(
        '/<li><a class="selected" href="post_'.$page.'.html">(.+)<\/a><\/li>/i',
        '/<li class="nolink">(.+)<\/li>/i',
     ),
     array(
        '',
        '<li class="nolink">\\1</li>',
     ),
     compact('topmenu','menu','add','counters')
  ),
```

EXTR_OVERWRITE);

This code works but I want add removing other type of links from menu. All with a class="selected" I try to write regex which will remove links from page but keep anchor.
so I have regex `<a class="selected" href="'.$page.'.html"([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>` which doesn't work. Looks like problem with matching of things after .html" and before > .

Link includes title and can unclude rel tag after .html". So typical link :`<a class="selected" href="connect.html" title="Email" rel="nofollow">Email</a>`
Hope you are better with php regex than me.

Comment: Why not http://uk3.php.net/domdocument and http://uk3.php.net/domxpath ?

Comment: Hey,cd001. I have working solution already just need regex to impove this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to remove only the link itself:

```
$link = '<a class="selected" href="connect.html" title="Email" rel="nofollow">Email</a>';
echo preg_replace('/(:?href=\")(.+?)(:?\")/', '$1$3', $link);
```

Will output:

```
<a class="selected" href="" title="Email" rel="nofollow">Email</a>
```

Or this if you want to remove the href tag completly:

```
$link = '<a class="selected" href="connect.html" title="Email" rel="nofollow">Email</a>';
echo preg_replace('/(href=\".+?\")/', '', $link);
```

Will output:

```
<a class="selected"  title="Email" rel="nofollow">Email</a>
```